# Regex to find text containing new line

Tags: c#, regex, find

TEST.*.TEST.*.    data data
    data TEST data data TEST data
    data data
    data data TEST
    data

I am new to regex and I have above text in notepad++. I tried using `TEST.*.\n.*.TEST.*.\n.*.TEST` to highlight the block which consists of all occurrences of TEST. When I use `TEST.*.TEST` it works to find  occurrences on one line. I would like to find and highlight all occurrences.

Comment: what is d expected output?

Comment: I wanted to find all occurrences of TEST

Comment: `\bTEST\b` would find them all - what do you want to do with them in C# when you've found them?

Comment: You might want to look into using `RegexOptions.Singleline` so that `.` (dot) will match newlines.

Comment: This is not clear. You won't get answers until its clear. Separate/highlight what you want to match/what you don't. There is no information about intent from your regex's.

Comment: edited original question. I am intended to find and highlight block which consists of all (here 3) occurrences of TEST. For example if I use TEST.*.TEST then it will find and highlight block on second line. So if I use TEST.*.\n.*.TEST.*.\n.*.TEST something like this then it will highlight 3 occurrences in my example.

Comment: @magg, be it that you are fairly new to regex. I'd like to recommend an excellent online tool that will make the process of learning the ropes and staying on them much simpler. I still use this in a professional setting and has always been my fall back when testing regex patterns in real time. http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: Thanks James, I am checking this tool. Seems to be good.

Comment: I've found the only tool needed to do regex processing is http://www.regexformat.com. All the other ones are bull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To highlight/match a block from first to last *TEST*

Try this `TEST(?:[\S\s]*TEST)?`

```
 TEST          # First TEST
 (?:           # Cluster group
      [\S\s]*       # any char's (greedy)
      TEST          # Last TEST
 )?            # End Cluster group, which is optional
```

Oytput

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 16 , len 51 ) 
TEST data data TEST data
data data
data data TEST
```

This can be 1 - 3 `TEST(?:[\S\s]*?TEST){0,2}`

This is exactly 3 `TEST(?:[\S\s]*?TEST){2}`

Comment: TEST(?:[\S\s]*TEST)? works fine. Thanks for the solution

Comment: Just small extended question. For example if there are 5 occurrences of TEST and we want to find and highlight only 3 then can we do that?

Comment: @magg - Ok, posted a 1-3 or 3 example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all occurances of TEST then just use TEST as the expression.

Comment: If i have text 'TEST data TEST' then i can use TEST.*.TEST to find it. But if there is new line after data then how regex will be able to find. That is my question.

Comment: @Alex k. your right, \bTESTb would be the right answer